# Using PHPMYADMIN with google cloud SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, phpmyadmin, cloud

I have just imported several GB of that into Google Cloud SQL and I would like to use any PHPMYADMIN client to connect to the DB.

I have tried using my local server where I have installed WAMP and where I run PHPMYADMIN locally.

**How can I configure PHPMYADMIN so I can have Google Cloud SQL as one of the Host I am allowed to connect to?**

Comment: Have you already tried any configurations? Can you share what you have tried and failed? Showing effort helps lead to more answers and better answers in the context of what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 3):

If somebody interesting how GC SQL working with external phpmyadmin now in aug 2021:

1. In GC SQL add new instance (or use existing on step 2);
2. Open instance ;
3. Open section "Users" (leftside menu) and add new user (or use root);
4. Open section "connections" (leftside menu);
5. Scroll to "Security/Manage client certificates" part;
6. Click "create client certificate" and there are will be 3 files to download and command line example with ip-address -- download them and copy ip-addr.;
7. Upload cert-files to your server;
8. Open phpmyadmin's config file, add new server-section and set smth like this:

```
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'gcloud';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx'; # GCSQL ip
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false; # or true if you set no-pass in GCS
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['key'] = '/var/lib/ssl/gcsql/client-key.pem';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['cert'] = '/var/lib/ssl/gcsql/client-cert.pem';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['ca'] = '/var/lib/ssl/gcsql/server-ca.pem';
```

And it should work on your hosted phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

You could use MySQL Workbench.
Follow the article below -

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-tools#workbench